# How to flood my router's NAT table?

Tags: ip, nat

I need to flood my router's NAT table for testing the boundary condition behavior of my Router. Apart from manual options( Opening enormous number of websites/Paraller downloads of Torrents/Nmap scan of Internet) is there any other tool or script available to achieve the required setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool widely used for testing networks : [iperf](https://github.com/esnet/iperf)

With the `-P <number>` option you can open a great number of flow simultaneously.

There's a default max of 128 for this option, but there's no hard limit. You can change this value editing the `src/iperf.h` file.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I'm familiar with iPerf and also have forked iPerf Source code for SCTP protocol as well. However,i would need an IP in the WAN IP subnet with enough ports opened to establish concurrent sessions to max out the NAT table entries(8096). That is where i need some help.However,thanks for reminding me the "-P" option.I will experiment on that.Cheers

Comment: Thanks it Worked. Recompiled iPerf and modified the Max Streams value.

Comment: glad it works. Out of curiosity, is it a linux-based router and which limit did you reach?

Comment: Yes,It is an Open-WRT based linux router.NAT is implemented with Iptables. However,I couldn't completely flood NAT tables.Even though i explicitly increased the MAX streams limit,the Connection started showing errors in iperf when i crossed 200+ parallel streams towards the same port. I think i will have to bind multiple Iperf Server sessions and allocate 200 streams for each server and then to eventually reach the 8196 limit on the NAT table.I'm currently exploring the other available options to flood the NAT tables.

Comment: Unfortunately it crashes for me when I specify anything larger than 510. Both the server (3.0.11 on 64 bit linux) and the client (iperf 3.1.7 on 64 bit linux) crashes.